# EXC_BAD_ACCES in swift when trying to manipulate the UITextField.text as a String

Tags: ios, swift

I have experienced a bug in an IOS app written in swift that I have been able to reproduce in a simple playground : the code is the following one :

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

var textField = UITextField()
textField.text = "Foo"
let content = textField.text
println(content.uppercaseString)
```

The error message is the following one :

Execution was interrupted, reason: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0).
The process has been left at the point where it was interrupted, use "thread return -x" to return to the state before expression evaluation.
* thread #1: tid = 0x657a84, 0x000000010be3e4c6, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)
  * frame #0: 0x000000010be3e4c6

On the other hand the following code works great :

```
let testString = "Bar"
println(testString.uppercaseString)
```

Is there something I have missed in memory management with Swift or in bridging String and NSString ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've reproduced the crash here and it looks suspiciously like you've found a bug in `uppercaseString` to me. File a bug with the code you've provided.

While Apple are fixing this, I got this workaround to work:

```
var upper = content.uppercaseStringWithLocale(NSLocale.currentLocale());
```

Comment: I've filed 17223180 on this with my test project. Feel free to dupe.

Comment: This equivalent Objective-C code works fine:

- (IBAction)buttonAction:(id)sender {
    self.textField.text = @"foo";
    NSString *val = self.textField.text;
    NSLog(@"val:%@", val);
    NSLog(@"val uppercase: %@", val.uppercaseString);
}

Comment: This is fixed in beta 3.

Comment: Same bug reappared in Xcode 6.3 beta. EXC_BAD_ADDRESS wasn't indicating the exact line involved, found the culprit only after 3 hours by bisecting code.